# Natural deduction in quantification logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

Can someone please help me on how to answer this using natural deduction?

$$\begin{array}{c}
(\exists x,\ F\ x) \supset (\exists x,\ (G\ x \land H\ x)) \\
(\exists x,\ (H\ x\lor K\ x)) \supset (\forall x,\ L\ x) \\
\hline
\forall x,\ F\ x \supset L\ x
\end{array}$$

Comment: Who are F, G, H, K, L ?

Comment: What does the "//" in line 2 stand for?

Comment: // this stands for therefore. what do you mean by who are F, G, H, K, L?

Comment: Your premises are 1 and 2, and you want to prove $\forall x,\ (F\ x \supset L\ x)$, and this for any predicate F, G, H, K, L, that's it ? I thought you wanted to prove 1, then prove 2, which cannot be done without linking F, G and H.

Comment: Yes, that's actually what my question is all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go through this proof step by step : )

The way I like to do Natural Deduction proofs is by building a tree-like structure (see Halbach's 'The Logic Manual' if you're unfamiliar).

Line 1: ∀Intro. So now we have (Fa -> La).

Line 2: ->Intro. So now we have La.

Line 3: ∃Elim. So we have ∃x(Gx^Hx) and La on the same line.

Let's focus on proving ∃x(Gx^Hx) first.

Line 4: ->Elim. We have ∃xFx -> ∃x(Gx^Hx) and ∃xFx on the same line.

∃xFx -> ∃x(Gx^Hx) is a premise, but we need to prove ∃xFx.

Line 5: ∃Intro. So we have Fa. Fa can be discharged at line 2.

Now to prove La.

Line 6: ∀Elim. So now we have ∀xLx.

Line 7: ->Elim. We have ∃x(Hx v Kx) -> ∀xLx and ∃x(Hx v Kx) on one line.

Now ∃x(Hx v Kx) -> ∀xLx is a premise but we need to prove ∃x(Hx v Kx).

Line 8: ∃Intro. So now we have (Ha v Ka).

Line 9: VIntro. So now we have Ha.

Line 10: ^Elim. So now we have (Ga ^ HA). This can be discharged at Line 3.

The proof is now complete. Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove $\forall x,\ (F\ x \supset L\ x)$, 
with premises 1 and 2.

By deduction theorem, you just need to prove $L\ x$ from premises 1, 2, $x$, $F\ x$.
By $\exists$ introduction, and premises $x$, $F\ x$, you can prove $\exists x,\ F\ x$.

Thus, by $\supset$ elimination, and premises 1 and $\exists x,\ F\ x$, you can prove $\exists x,\ G\ x \land H\ x$, then extract the witness $y$.

Now, your premises are 1, 2, $\exists x,\ F\ x$, $y$, $G\ y$, $H\ y$.

By $\lor$ introduction, and premise $H\ y$, you have $H\ y \lor K\ y$, which can be changed by $\exists$ introduction as $\exists y,\ H\ y \lor K\ y$.

By $\supset$ elimination, you can thus prove $\forall x,\ L\ x$, and in particular $L\ x$ for your particular x.